# Adding a UNIQUE key to a large existing MySQL table which is receiving INSERTs/DELETEs

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, percona

I have a very large table (dozens of millions of rows) and a UNIQUE index needs to be added to a column on that table. I know for a fact that the table does contain duplicated values on that key, which I need to clean up (by deleting rows/resetting the value of the column to something unique that I can automatically generate). A plus is that the rows which are already duplicated do not get modified anymore.

What would be the right approach to perform a change like this, given that I will be probably using the Percona pt-osc tool and there are continuous deletes/inserts on the table? My plan was:

- Add code that ensures no dupe IDs get inserted anymore. Probably I need to add a separate table for this temporarily, since I want the database to enforce this for me and not the application - so insert into the "shadow table" with a unique index in a transaction together with my main table, rollback all inserts that try to insert duplicate values
- Backfill the table by zapping all invalid column values which are within the primary key range below `$current_pkey_value`
- Then add the index and use pt-osc to changeover the table

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we use `pt-online-schema-change` we are using triggers for performing the synchronisation from the existing table to a temp table. The tool actually has a special configuration key for this, `--no-check-unique-key-change`, which will do exactly what we need - agree to perform the ALTER TABLE and set up triggers in such a way that if a conflict occurs, `INSERT .. IGNORE` will be applied and the first row having used the now-unique value will win in the insert during synchronisation. For us this is a good tradeoff because all the duplicates we have seen resulted from data races, not from actual conflicts in the value generation process.